# Link Queries with Realm Android

Tags: android, realm

I have the following classes:

```
public class Recipe  extends RealmObject {

  @PrimaryKey
  private long id;

  private String title;
  private String description;
  private RealmList<Ingredient> ingredients;
  private String imageUrl;
}

public class Ingredient extends RealmObject{

  @PrimaryKey
  private long id;

  private String name;
  private String category;
}
```

I need to find all the recipes that have the ingredients obtained through a SharedPreferences. This is the code I have to get the ids of the ingredients that I have to look for in all the recipes:

```
public RealmResults<Recipe> getRecipesByIngredients(){

    SharedPreferences prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("INGREDIENTS_USER_FILE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Map<String, ?> allEntries =  prefs.getAll();


    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
        Log.d("map values", entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());
        String id = entry.getValue().toString();
    }
}
```

I can not make a query that from a list of ids look in all the recipes stored in my db recipes that are made with the ingredients obtained.

Edit: 
This is an example of SharedPreferences of ingredients:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<string name="IngredienteEspecias1">9</string>
<string name="IngredienteEspecias2">10</string>
<string name="IngredienteCarne0">12</string>
<string name="IngredienteEspecias0">0</string>
</map>
```

Numbers are the ids of the ingredients

Comment: how do you **save the IDs to the shared preferences**

Comment: I added an example of my SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public RealmResults<Recipe> getRecipesByIngredients(){

    SharedPreferences prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("INGREDIENTS_USER_FILE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Map<String, ?> allEntries =  prefs.getAll();

    List<Long> ingredientIds = new ArrayList<>();    
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
        Log.d("map values", entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());
        String id = entry.getValue().toString();
        ingredientIds.add(Long.valueOf(id));
    }


    RealmQuery<Recipe> query  = realm.where(Recipe.class);
    if(ingredientIds.size()  > 0) {
          query.beginGroup().equalTo("ingredients.id", ingredientIds.get(0));
          for (int i = 1; i < ingredientIds.size() ; i++) {
              query.or().equalTo("ingredients.id", ingredientIds.get(i));
          }
          query.endGroup();
    } 
    return query.findAll();
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much! I think the query will work, but I have a problem, Android Studio tells me the following: Can not resolve method 'in (java.lang.String, java.lang.Object [])' if I add a cast a (Long []), when Running the console indicates the following: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object [] can not be cast to java.lang.Long []

Comment: Hold on i'ma fix that up

Comment: Okay I hope I didn't mess up the syntax from this phone

Comment: Sorry, the query works, but it returns a recipe if any ingredient is in the list ingredientsIds and I need that all ingredients of recipe are in list to add the recipe to the RealmResults. Thanks

Comment: I'd say just remove the `or()` and try

Comment: It is not solved by removing or (), the same thing is still happening.